# Filter empty the array after click on custom event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to practice vue application using props but when I click on the the name, I tried to do `console.log` the problem but it hasn't helped me. Maybe I am new to `filter` option but I want to know what I am doing wrong?

#### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>All Friends</h1>
   <AllFriends :Totalfriends="friends" />
   <h1>Online Friends</h1>
   <OnlineFriends :Totalfriends="friends" @toggleStatus="toggleStatus" />
  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import AllFriends from "./components/AllFriends"
import OnlineFriends from "./components/OnlineFriends"
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    AllFriends,
    OnlineFriends
  },
  data(){
    return{
      friends: [
        {name:'Mario', online: true},
        {name:'Luigi', online: false},
        {name:'Todd', online: true},
        {name:'Bowzer', online: false}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleStatus(payload){
      this.friends = this.friends.filter((friend)=>{
        if(friend !== payload){
           console.log(friend)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

OnlineFriends.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      Online Friends
      <div v-for="(friends, index) in Totalfriends" :key="index">
          <p @click="toggleStatus(friends.name)" v-if="friends.online">{{friends.name}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:["Totalfriends"],
    methods: {
        toggleStatus(friend){
            this.$emit("toggleStatus",{friend})
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

AllFriends.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      All Friends
      <div v-for="(friend, index) of Totalfriends" :key="index">
          <p>{{friend.name}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "AllFriends",
    props: ["Totalfriends"]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Filter expects a boolean. So like `this.friends = this.friends.filter(f => return f !== payload)`, or without return: `this.friends = this.friends.filter(f => (f !== payload))`

Comment: I didn't understand what is missing?

Comment: You are not returning the boolean, you just log the friend. the return is undefined. And maybe you want do compare their name (if the name is an ID) not the objects itself... so `...filter(f => (f.name !== payload.name))`

Comment: Did it solve your problem?